# How to wrap an asynchronous Java lib in Android Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, listener

I would like to use a Java Library inside of my Kotlin Android App, but I am relatively new to Kotlin and need some advice. The Library basically looks like this:

```
public interface Listener{
    void onResult(Result res)
}

public class Client{
    public Client(){}
    public void setListener(Listener l){}
    public void start(){} // Starts Thread(s) (so it's non-blocking), does some server calls, computes result, calls listener.onResult(res) after computation is finished.
    public void cancel(){} 
}
```

Yes, I know, I could just call the functions directly and use it like in java, but is that the Kotlin way?
I read, doing a similar task (using an asynchronous function, which takes a callback parameter) would be done by wrapping it in a coroutine/suspend function structure.
But I don't know howto adapt this for my Problem(?) or is it the wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make this into a nice easy Kotlin suspending function, it would be like this:

```
suspend fun doTheThing() : Result {
    val c = Client()
    try {
        //suspend until the listener fires or we're cancelled
        return suspendCancellableCoroutine {
            cont ->
            c.setListener {
                result -> cont.resume(result)
            }
            c.start()
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // If someone cancels the parent job, our job will complete exceptionally
        // before the client is done.  Cancel the client since we don't need it
        // anymore
        c.cancel()
        throw e
    }
}
```

I don't see a way in your interface for the client to indicate failure.  If that's part of `Result` then you probably want to turn that into an exception in the listener

Comment: Thanks Matt, thats pretty cool, but it also leads me to some further questions.
1. Is it possible to move the initialization (constructor and more interesting setListener) out of the function?
I am having an other Library which basically works like this in java:
```
Client c = new Client();
Config con = new Config();
con.listener = new Listener(); 
// ... further config members
c.initWithConfig(con); // relatively heavy, so doing it every time won't be nice
c.start()
```

2. What should e be? Is there a special JobCanceledException or is Exception just fine?

Comment: 2:  When you catch e the exception is thrown and you are already done, so you want to cancel the client no matter what kind of exception it is.  1. Yes, sure, then you have to make sure you disconnect the listener when you're done so it doesn't get called for the next request on the same client.

Comment: 2. But this isn't Python, the Compiler needs a type for e ;-) What is best practise (Exception, Throwable, replace catch with finally)?

Comment: Oh, typo.  I didn't compile it. It's just exception

Comment: 1. Sorry, I don't get it. How would i do that? Can you elaborate it further maybe with code, please?
Meta: I am also new in using stackoverflow actively, is it okay/best practise to discuss here in the comments?